# Hg653 redirect certain users to url

Tags: ssh, router

I tried ssh but ran into the issues below

when looking on the routers webpage i cant seem to find anyway to enable its SSH, does it even have ssh and if so how do i enable it, i tried using putty to connect to its address and it didn't work.

These are the tabs under 'maintain'

System Information
Account Management
Device Management
Remote Management
Statistics
System Logs
Diagnosis Tools


remote management has ACS access settings, is that to do with it?

The reason I wish to do this is to redirect uers to a URL when they use the router for the first time, I have already found a way to do this but I requires me to enter a command into the router, assuming this is actually possible with the talktalk super router I would assume it would be via ssh basically I need to find a way to enter in commands to my router but the settings page does not seem to offer any way of doing so

Comment: What makes you think it should have SSH?

Comment: well i am not certian, i think i have have found an alternate way of achiveing my final goal so i will probs just delete this q, but thx anyway @MichaelKjörling

Comment: While you are here, then, I suggest you review [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730) on [meta.se].

Comment: Well what I am trying to do (x) is get certain users re-directed to a certain page when using my WiFi, the router I now know is a hg635